# Sitecore Forms app missing in Sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

After updating to Sitecore 9.1.1 I do not see the built in Forms app. Instead i see the Experience Profile with a broken icon. Is it possible to install Sitecore Forms?

What I see:

[image]

What I should see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try go to your core database and check under the path /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Marketing. See if everything is correct for you. And you can arrange the apps and icon from here. The screenshot I attached is not from a sitecore 9 instance but to give an idea where it is.
[launchpad apps in core database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PBUE.png)